# Unable to Send Emails Using Redemption.SafeMailItem

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-redemption, outlook-2016

I would like to send emails without getting the **Outlook warnings** hence the use of **Redemption.SafeMailItem.** However, my emails don't send. I have a feeling it may be the **RDOSession.session** I'm not getting right but I'm not sure. What may I be missing?

```
Sub UsingRDO()
'/*This script uses Redemption Com add in to send emails*/
Dim OlMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim RDOSafeMail As Redemption.SafeMailItem
Dim AttachmentStr As String
Dim RDOSesh As Redemption.RDOSession

Set RDOSesh = New Redemption.RDOSession
Set OlMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(ItemType:=olMailItem)
Set RDOSafeMail = New Redemption.SafeMailItem
AttachmentStr = "C:\Users\Kennedy_Ngugi\Desktop\Faiba\"
       
RDOSesh.Logon , , False, False
        
        With OlMail
                .Body = "Hello" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a Test Email"
                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                .To = "somebody.someone@madhatter.co.ke"
                .CC = "somebody.someone@madhatter.co.ke"
                .Subject = "Internet Connectivity Test Email"
                .Attachments.Add AttachmentStr & "Kitchen Catalogue.png"
                .Attachments.Add AttachmentStr & "Sitting Room Catalogue.jpeg"
                .Attachments.Add AttachmentStr & "Madhatter COMPANY PROFILE.pdf"
                '.DeferredDeliveryTime = #8/1/2024 6:30:49 AM#
                
        End With
        
        RDOSafeMail.Send
        
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not assigning the mailitem to the safemailitem: `RDOSafeMail.Item = OlMail` before you send it.

Comment: Hey Rory, Thank you for taking the time. I've inserted your suggestion before RDOSafeMail.Send I can see "another program is using outlook" but I can't see whether my message has been sent. Also, the code in code window has exited out.

Comment: Hey @Rory, I meant to say thank you. I had to capture "outlook" in the RDOSesh.logon profile name parameter including your script. My messages sent.